# how do I find the "code contracts" for dotnet libraries

Tags: c#, code-contracts

I'm just starting out on this, and if I get an unproven ensures. That's fine IF I know what the contracts are on the methods I'm calling, if I don't know the contracts I'm guessing.

BUT, even though this would seem to be a large point about the contracts, can I find them anywhere? no.

e.g. what is the contract on IDictionary.Add?

I've read the Microsoft official docs and trawled the internet, I expected them to turn up in intellisense, I'll go and have a look at the object browser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Install the [Code Contracts Editor Extensions](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/02de7066-b6ca-42b3-8b3c-2562c7fa024f) from Microsoft Research to get intellisense support for code contracts.

Comment: it did work...but it only works in a lmited way on 2013...but good enough for me that's....the answer